# Axis id and Feedback id in CANopen

Tags: can-bus, canopen

The **error message** in the CANopen protocol is as follows:

[image]

Based on the **error code** and **error register**, we can understand the problem message in the network, but I had two questions:

1- What are the two expressions, **Axis id**, and **Feedback id**?

2- How can we adjust these items?

Comment: Where in the CANopen spec CiA 301 did you find this? If you are reading some other document, then stop - these things are clearly from some custom implementation.

Comment: @Lundin I found this subject in **AKD2G CANopen**. Is this issue separate from the CiA 301 standard?

Comment: Yes that's some specific product manual.